# What VPS can do?

Tags: hosting, vps

I am new to VPS. My shared hosting plan dont allow me to install chat script in my website.
They require me to get VPS hosting.

I have now a Free VPS with
    128MB RAM
    10GB Disk Space
    Unlimited Bandwidth

```
Instant Setup
OpenVZ Virtualization
Linux OS
```

Why they require me into this VPS hosting?
Can i install a game/chat script? can i host unlimited website?
can i host unlimited domain?
can i install red5?
can i make a streaming wbsite? how can i? do i need to install any software in my vps?

Other said that you can do anything you want in VPS hosting? why?
is it like a computer? that i can install all software? 
*emphasized text*

Comment: This is not about programming, and is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You can ask the support team, they will give you a better answer.

Comment: oh sorry. i thought it is ok to ask about this. thanks.. how can i delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , a vps server is a virtual machine so it's not really a machine but it simulates a machine so , yes you'll need to install an Os like a linux distribution.

Example: For debian then you'll need to install all what a web server needs , with the terminal so it's not that easy , i mean that it is easier to install a chat script on shared hosting my friend.

And no you do not need a vps for a chatting script , and if you need a chat room then [here](http://freenode.net/) is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

A virtual private server (VPS) is a virtual machine sold as a service by an Internet hosting service. A VPS runs its own copy of an operating system, and customers have superuser-level access to that operating system instance, so they can install almost any software that runs on that OS.

There are limitations in shared hosting plans while in VPS you will have root access to install any application that OS support. It is like your own server, but resources are shared between different VPS on the main node. So each VPS is allocated it own resources.